# Lucene: Am I correctly parsing the strings ? Terms or Phrases?

Tags: java, syntax, lucene, indexing

I'm new to Lucene. If I use

```
description = new TermQuery(new Term("description", "my string"));
```

I ask Lucene to consider "my string" as unique word, right ?

I actually need to consider each word, should I use PhraseQuery instead ? Or is it correct ?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lucene Term [Consructor](http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_0_3/api/all/org/apache/lucene/index/Term.html#Term%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) says

Term:
public Term(String fld,String txt)

Constructs a Term with the given field and text.

It means the field shall be **description** and **"my string"** would be content of the term.

You are just constructing a term, it doesnt say anything about the search results(Uniqueness or whatever)

If you need to consider each word,use a [Booleanquery](http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_0_3/api/all/org/apache/lucene/search/BooleanQuery.html) and add the required conditions there

Comment: @Narayan ok. I thought I need to use a PhraseQuery and not a BooleanQuery though. If I use a BooleanQuery I should parse the string by myself right ?

Comment: @Patrick yes, you need to pass "my String" to build a BooleanQuery e.g.;
**TermQuery tq= new TermQuery(new Term("Description", desc));
BooleanQuery bq = new BooleanQuery().add(tq,BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD);**

Comment: @Narayan But in this way the content of Description is still indexed as term and not a phrase.

Comment: @Patrick, the above comments shows you how to build a BooleanQUery, it doesnot index them as you presume in your last comment, you should parse the term and index them as a whole(_"my String"_ corresponging to field _Description_) and then use a Boolean Query to find them. In My experience PhraseQuery has the problem with searching,it doesnt work with wildcards, and it doesn't find the string match, even if the documents contain them. try it,luke debug it,post the results, i would be glad to see them

Comment: @Narayan yeah I wrongly wrote indexed instead of added. What I meant is that you are telling me how to build a boolean query based on multiple terms, but what I'm asking is how to split my sentences into multiple terms (to pass to the booleanQuery)

Comment: @Patrick dont index fields into multiple terms, if you plan to do,ask yourself what will be the field name,will it be same for each term?, my suggestion would be to index the whole Field as a single Data Store(no tokenization) as during indexation, the Analyzer won't be called for these fields,  with the same Analyzer, then  build the search term,QueryParser can then find the terms you are finding using BooleanQuery

Comment: @Narayan uhm, I'm currently passing a query to the booleanQuery.add method. Does it make sense ? booleanQuery.add(new QueryParser(org.apache.lucene.util.Version.LUCENE_40, "tags", new WhitespaceAnalyzer(org.apache.lucene.util.Version.LUCENE_40)).parse(phrase[i]); Does it make sense ?

Comment: By the way, I don't know Data Store... In the indexing process I'm using a WhiteSpaceAnalyzer, so I guess I need to tokenize the query strings as well. (This is the indexing code:   document.add(new Field("description", flickrDoc.getDescription(), Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED));

Comment: @Patrick since u say, u tokenize while indexing, open the index in Luke, try to search with the whitespaceanalyzer, and while searching use the same analyzer, it should work with booleanquery, use a MultiFieldQueryParser, since you index with tokenized terms

Comment: @Narayan I actually need to code it, and I cannot use Luke. I wrote before the code line I'm using to parse the string and pass it to the booleanQuery... however I'm not sure it is doing its job correctly. What do you think ? booleanQuery.add(new QueryParser(org.apache.lucene.util.Version.LUCENE_40, "tags", new WhitespaceAnalyzer(org.apache.lucene.util.Version.LUCENE_40)).parse("tag1 tag2 tag3");